# CourseModuleUpdateView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

I have the following class for displaying related course module using formsets

```
class CourseModuleUpdateView(TemplateResponseMixin, View):
    template_name = 'courses/manage/module/formset.html'
    course = None

    def get_formset(self, data=None):
        return ModuleFormSet(instance=self.course, data=data)

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.course = get_object_or_404(Course,
                                        id=kwargs['pk'],
                                        owner=request.user)
        super(CourseModuleUpdateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formset = self.get_formset()
        return self.render_to_response({'course': self.course, 'formset': formset})
```

Url pattern responsible for this CBV

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/module/$', views.CourseModuleUpdateView.as_view(), name='course_mudule_update')
```

Issuing a get request I get the following error

Traceback:

```
File "/home/mtali/.virtualenvs/educa/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/mtali/.virtualenvs/educa/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  198.                 "returned None instead." % (callback.__module__, view_name)

Exception Type: ValueError at /courses/4/module/ Exception Value: The view courses.views.CourseModuleUpdateView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

What is wrong with my code! I am using django 1.11

Comment: Could you try with "return super(CourseModuleUpdateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)" in the dispatch method.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked! But why should I return` super().dispatch()` since on its parent it return the get and post handles!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch) dispatch method should return a HTTP response.

> `dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)`
>
> The view part of the view – the
> method that accepts a request argument plus arguments, and **returns a
> HTTP response.**

***Explanation based on your code.***

From the source code of Django `View` class,

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Try to dispatch to the right method; if a method doesn't exist,
        # defer to the error handler. Also defer to the error handler if the
        # request method isn't on the approved list.
        if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
            handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(), self.http_method_not_allowed)
        else:
            handler = self.http_method_not_allowed
        return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

[dispatch](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L80) method is not only delegates the requested method to the corresponding handler it also r**eturns back the handler response**.

i.e., In this line.

```
return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

In your case you are invoking `super(CourseModuleUpdateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)` in your `dispatch` method, this will invoke the superclass's dispatch method(i.e., `View` class dispatch method). Since your requested http method is `GET` after executing the following line on the `dispatch` method

```
handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(), self.http_method_not_allowed)
```

handler will be assigned to `get`. So in this case it is roughly equivalent to

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

This `get` will invoke the `get` method in your `CourseModuleUpdateView` class
i.e.,

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formset = self.get_formset()
        return self.render_to_response({'course': self.course, 'formset': formset})
```

Which returns a valid HTTP response.

This response will reach the place where the `get` method is called. i.e., Inside `View`s dispatch method. And from there it will return the response from where it is invoked i.e., `super(CourseModuleUpdateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)`. Since your not returning response that you received from the `dispatch` method resulting in

```
Exception Type: ValueError at /courses/4/module/ Exception Value: The view courses.views.CourseModuleUpdateView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```